# Python/ Django- copying buttons from one HTML page to another

Tags: python, html, django

I have just taken over the development of some project management software that has been written in Python/ Django- having not used Python or Django much at all before...

There are a few buttons displayed on one of the webpages that it would be useful to display on another page within the application. I can see that these buttons are defined in `budget.html` with the following code:

```
{% block page_options %}
    <a class="button m-r-md" href="{% url 'costing:export_csv' budget.id %}">Export to Excel</a>
    <a class="button m-r-md" href="{% url 'costing:schedule_of_works_post_dep' budget.id %}" target="_blank">Schedule of works</a>
    <a class="button m-r-md" href="?pdf=1" target="_blank">PDF</a>
    <input data-view-url="{% url 'costing:combined_budget' project.id %}?search=" type="text" id="item_search" placeholder="Item search" />
{% endblock page_options %}
```

The other page, where I want to be able to use them- `variations.html` has the following code already in its `{%block page_options %}` block:

```
{% block page_options %}
    <button class="button modalBtn" name="variation">+ Add variation</button>

    <a class="button" href="{% url 'costing:add_omit_builder' project.id %}">+ Add group</a>

    <a class="button" id="scas" data-view-url="{% url 'costing:preview_scas' project.budget_overview.version.id %}" href="{% url 'costing:scas_2_variations' project.budget_overview.version.id %}">+ Standard cost assumptions</a>

    <!--ERF(17/11/2016 @ 1700) Add buttons to export adds/ omits table to excel -->


{% endblock page_options %}
```

So I tried copying and pasting the code from the first page into this block in the second page:

```
{% block page_options %}
    <button class="button modalBtn" name="variation">+ Add variation</button>

    <a class="button" href="{% url 'costing:add_omit_builder' project.id %}">+ Add group</a>

    <a class="button" id="scas" data-view-url="{% url 'costing:preview_scas' project.budget_overview.version.id %}" href="{% url 'costing:scas_2_variations' project.budget_overview.version.id %}">+ Standard cost assumptions</a>

    <!--ERF(17/11/2016 @ 1700) Add buttons to export adds/ omits table to excel -->
        <a class="button m-r-md" href="{% url 'costing:export_csv' budget.id %}">Export to Excel</a>
<a class="button m-r-md" href="{% url 'costing:schedule_of_works_post_dep' budget.id %}" target="_blank">Schedule of works</a>
<a class="button m-r-md" href="?pdf=1" target="_blank">PDF</a>
<input data-view-url="{% url 'costing:combined_budget' project.id %}?search=" type="text" id="item_search" placeholder="Item search" />


{% endblock page_options %}
```

but when I now try viewing this page in the browser, I get an error page which says:

> NoReverseMatch at /costing/5915/variations/

I'm not sure why I'm getting this error... do I need to reference any of the calls to the views that I'm using in the code I've copied in elsewhere in the HTML file? Both of the HTML files are in the same app, so share the same `models.py` file- so I would have thought that they would both be able to use all of the `models` & `views` defined within this app?

Is this the case? If so, why am I getting this error on the variations page?

Comment: If you're copying and pasting code, you're already doing something wrong.

Comment: However, if you want real help, you need to post the *full* error and traceback.

Answer (score 0):

Based on what you said I suppose problem is that your don't have "budget" value in context variable. I think that view which using first template send "budget" in it's context. 
But second view don't. That is why when you try to get budget.id in the second template you get the error.

Try to modify context in your view and add "budget" variable to it.

```
def my_view(request, pk):
    budget= get_object_or_404(Budget, pk=pk)
    return render(request, 'budget.html', {'budget': budget})
```

Or if you are using class based view you should override get_context_data method:

```
def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
    context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
    context['budget'] = self.budget
    return context
```